# c++でのLEAPMOTIONのプログラムについて

Tags: c++, leap-motion

最近LEAPMOTIONのプログラムをc++で作ってみようとしたのですが、例えばIndex fingerのMiddle boneのy座標のような、各要素を取り出す方法が分かりません。x,y,z全てを同時に表示させる方法はサンプルから読み取れるのですが、一つに注目する方法が分かりません。

```
 for (int b = 0; b < 4; ++b) {
    Bone::Type boneType = static_cast<Bone::Type>(b);
    Bone bone = finger.bone(boneType);
    std::cout << std::string(6, ' ') <<  boneNames[boneType]
              << " bone, start: " << bone.prevJoint()
              << ", end: " << bone.nextJoint()
              << ", direction: " << bone.direction() << std::endl;}
```

これがサンプルプログラムの一部で、各指の各骨の始点、終点、角度などが、(x,y,z)の形で返されます。これのyの値のみを取得する方法が分からないです。

Comment: 例(可能ならばコードも)を出した方が回答を得られやすいと思います。

Comment: アドバイスいただき、ソースを追加しました。

Answer (score 1):

これではダメなのですか？
`Leap::Bone::prevJoint()`等の返す型は`Leap::Vector`で、各要素は`float`型のようでした。

```cpp
for (int b = 0; b < 4; ++b) {
    Bone::Type boneType = static_cast<Bone::Type>(b);
    Bone bone = finger.bone(boneType);
    float startPointY = bone.prevJoint().y
    float endPointY = bone.nextJoint().y
    float directionY = bone.direction().y

    // 表示処理等
    std::cout << "start.y" << startPointY << std::endl;
    std::cout << "end.y" << endPointY << std::endl;
    std::cout << "direction.y" << directionY << std::endl;
}
```

参考URL：
[Leap::Boneクラス](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/cpp/api/Leap.Bone.html)
[Leap::Vectorクラス](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/cpp/api/Leap.Vector.html)